# Middle mouse button doesn't open or close tabs in browser

Tags: windows, firefox, mouse

I was using **Logitech M-100** mouse and everything worked well. Then I've plugged in **X7 XL-755BK** mouse which worked perfect on my previous laptop. But this time middle button doesn't open links in new tabs and doesn't close tabs when I click them. Moreover, if I click middle button, it scrolls the current page (not only in browser) to the very bottom.

The browser I use is **Firefox 68.9.0esr** with some extensions. However everything worked with the same extensions with that other mouses
The system is **Windows 10**

Answer (score 8):

Funnily enough the taskbar locker or unlocked question solved it for me, apparently it's a bug with windows, just toggle the option on/off and then back, and it fixed the issue for me. Unclear but saved me trouble, thanks.
Disclaimer, I don't understand why it stopped working for me in the first place, so it could have been an unrelated bug and just a coincidence, but doesn't take much to try it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "just toggle the option on/off and then back, and it fixed the issue for me" **WHICH OPTION AND WHERE**???

Comment: Hey, I don`t understant how and why this worked, but based on this post, I unlocked, and locked my windows taskbar and it fixed the middle mouse button issue for me. Very weird indeed.

Comment: Successfully tested on Windows 10 : right-click in the middle of the Windows taskbar, toggle the menu item "Lock the taskbar". Then, redo the same action and toggle again the same menu item item (i.e. put it in the same state as before). Test in the browser without rebooting or restarting the application.

Comment: This also worked for me.  Tbh I was embarrassed to even try such an odd solution :)

Answer (score 5):

I recently bought a Logitech M510 and ran into the same problem. I did the following to assign middle mouse click to open link in a new tab (Windows 10):

1. Download Logitech Options - https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/options
2. Select 'Mouse' and 'middle mouse button' in the tool
3. Select 'Advanced Click' -> Click + Ctrl + Shift  (Ctrl + Shift + Left Click is the keyboard shortcut to open link in a new tab which we assign to the middle mouse button)
   [image]
4. You can also do this assignment just for a specific application e.g. Chrome
   [image]

Comment: I (logitech mx master 3) also needed to update from 'logitech options' to 'logitech options +' 

2: then i was able to use 'advanced click'  (ctrl + shift + click) as mentioned above with printscreens; however, it looks a bit different now

(needed to do it twice, first time it did not saved 'options +' as my new "mouse setting program"

Comment: At least in my version of Logitech Options, the "All Applications" (upper right) option now seems to have been replaced by "Upgrade to Options+" The link there does not work. A separate search leads to a downloadable installer. But that Options+ software, too, does not seem to offer (in Win10) an option to open a new tab by clicking the middle button.

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but....
I had this problem - turned the mouse off and back on. Fixed.
It may not fix everyone, but give it a go

Answer (score 3):

Hello can you check the taskbar in taskbar settings is locked or not?

Comment: How does that matter?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, with a Logitech MX Anywhere 3, using the same Logitech Options software, the middle button didn't close the browser tabs. Instead, used inside Notepad++ (just an example) it worked as usual, so it closed the tabs.

The issue was due to the activation of application presets in Logitech Options, where for Google and Edge application presets, the middle button wasn't set as default "Middle button" but was set as "Open link in new tab".